# Get Values from NSTextFields in Subclassed NSTableView

Tags: swift, nstableview, ibaction

I have a reoccurring problem that I have not found a clean solution for.  I have a NSTableView in NSViewController that uses a subclass of NSTableView to implement the datasource and delegate protocols e.g.

```
class SecondEdit: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var subTrackTable: NSTableView!

   var sublist = SubTrackListing()

 func loadTable() { 
    // other stuff left out for brevity 
    subTrackTable.setDataSource(sublist)              
    subTrackTable.setDelegate(sublist)

    subTrackTable.reloadData()
}
```

in particular it should be noted that the XIB file for the WindowController contains the Table and the outlet for the table is connected to the NSWindowController class.

```
 class SubTrackListing: NSTableView,  NSTableViewDataSource,      NSTableViewDelegate  {

   Usual NSTableView Delegate etc functions

  }
```

This works like a charm and properly displays all of the data and keeps the required NSTableView functions in their own (smallish) class (desirable in as the Window / ViewController classes get pretty bloated by themselves).

My Problem is that I have NOT found a way to get user edits from the Table's texfields.  IF the windowController class was also the NSTableView datasource / delegate, it would be trivial.  I would just hook up the textfields IBActions and grab the sender stringValues.  In the subclassed case, although you can hook up the IBActions just like before, THEY NEVER FIRE.  I have tried setting the NSTableView subclass in IBs Custom Class dialog and putting the textfields in the SubTrackListing class, but not only does IB fight you on this every step of the way (you can't just drag from IB to the NSTableView subclass, you have to code the IBAction in the subclass first and then - sometimes - you can drag from the IBActions circle to the textfield in IB and get a recognized hook up), the IBAction - even when Xcode seems to think it's hooked up - NEVER FIRES (!).  So I ask what the _____ !is going on here and how can you get NSTableView input from a subclassed NSTableView.

And yes I could just shove the NSTableView functions into the NSWindowController class, but not only would there be the what if you have more than one table situation, I have the general feeling that there Ought to be A Way to DO THIS in a subclass. . .
Any help would be appreciated. . .

Comment: Is the SubTrackListing delegate outlet connected to File's Owner?

Comment: SubTrackListing doesn't have a XIB file.  It just contains the delegate/data source methods.  Connecting the tableView in the SecondEdit XIB file to dataSource & delegate merely produces an illegal data source message (after all the requisite methods are in the SubTrackListing class )